# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException in CXF

Tags: apache, web-services, rest, soap, cxf

I got the below exception in **apache-cxf-3.1.2** and tried a lot to resolve it and did not get any positive help, So planned and upgraded to the latest version **apache-cxf-3.1.4** , but bad luck issue remains same in **apache-cxf-3.1.4**

```
 DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace 
Location:  node: [wsd:Types: null]
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
- with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:770)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:766)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:819)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:814)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.processValue(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:155)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:589)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:213)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:255)
at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(JAXBUtils.java:187)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:502)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:420)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.udp.UDPDestination$MCastListener$2.run(UDPDestination.java:114)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:369)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:817)
... 41 more
```

Please find the cxf.xml and web.xml below,

**cxf.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <!-- <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /> -->
    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/Restful">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="Service" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean id="Service" class="com.xxx.yyy.services.ServiceImpl" />
    </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>V1.6</display-name>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/cxf.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>com.xxx.yyy.services.InitListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**Further Details:**

Applicaion server : Tomcat 7

JDK/JRE Version : 1.7.0_75

**Question :**

1. I did any misconfiguration that cause this exception? or it is related to CXF version?
2. Is there any way to resolve this annoying exception.

**FYI,**

- it works fine with apache-cxf-2.7.17
- and this exception not stopping any functionalities.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have [WS-Discovery](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html) turned on. This is done by placing `cxf-services-ws-discovery-service` and `cxf-services-ws-discovery-api` in the classpath. Remove these from your classpath (e.g. from maven pom.xml) and you should no longer see the error messages.

Comment: i am not using maven here , and i have given my cxf.xml and web.xml above, do you know how to remove cxf-services-ws-discovery-api ? In my knowledge i don't use it specifically

Comment: Do i need to remove any JARs from CXF, to resove this?

Comment: Exactly. Try removing them and see what happens :)

Comment: It seems removing these JARs from CXF resolve the issue ,
cxf-services-ws-discovery-api-3.1.4.jar 
cxf-services-ws-discovery-service-3.1.4.jar
cxf-services-wsn-api-3.1.4.jar 
cxf-services-wsn-core-3.1.4.jar

However do you know ,whether this will affect any of CXF functionality?

Comment: No, it will not affect your scenario as WS-Discovery and WS-Notifications are not needed for RESTful services.

Answer (score 1):

If the above solution doesn't work, i repaired the same error by changing the project facet configuration.

go to your project properties-> project facets turn off CXF 2.x Web Services, and check that dynamic web module is On. if you are deploying on Jboss or Wildfly 8.x they will use the necesary cfx libraries that you need and are declared on your pom.xml