# Error within Apache CXF when unmarshalling WS-Discovery SOAP messages for ONVIF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, onvif

I am currently working on a Java application that runs on an embedded device and offers various functions to configure and control the device via a web interface. The device also has a camera, and so one of the requirements for the upcoming software release is the implementation some of the features ([Profile S](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/profile-s/)) of the [ONVIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONVIF) specification to support the integration into compliant video management systems. Since the initial detection of compliant devices is done via [WS-Discovery](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/discovery/1.1/wsdd-discovery-1.1-spec.pdf) (SOAP over UDP), we were trying a first approach for the implementation by utilizing [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-discovery.html) (version 3.2.4), which seems to work out-of-the-box.

Now, if I read the respective part in the [ONVIF Core Specification](https://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Specification-v1712.pdf) (chapter 7.2) correctly, a discoverable device should also listen and respond to Probe and Resolve message, and that's already where it gets a little bit tricky, because we are experiencing the following issue:

Some other devices on our network (I am not sure which ones yet) are periodically sending Probe messages in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" xmlns:wsdp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/devprof">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:To>urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</wsa:To>
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a9a24485-7fbd-48bb-bcfc-cce7d98add73</wsa:MessageID>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <wsd:Probe>
            <wsd:Types>wsdp:Device</wsd:Types>
        </wsd:Probe>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the body part of the SOAP message contains a part `<wsd:Types>wsdp:Device</wsd:Types>`, which should be a correct formatting according to the respective part in the [OASIS WS-Discovery Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-dd/discovery/1.1/wsdd-discovery-1.1-spec.pdf) (chapter 5.2). However, when CXF is trying to unmarshall and validate this message with JAXB, we get the following error:

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace 
     Location:  node: [wsd:Types: null]
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:753)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:749)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$24.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:807)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$24.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:802)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.processValue(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:125)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:50)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:572)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:198)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:354)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(JAXBUtils.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.udp.UDPDestination$MCastListener$2.run(UDPDestination.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:421)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:346)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$24.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:805)
    ... 40 more
```

Due to this error the respective webservice endpoint is not called and the Probe message is not handled/answered correctly. But imho (and also that of a colleague) the Probe message should actually validate correctly, because the required namespace is present in the SOAP envelope of the message.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with CXF already, and knows a hint for me to solve this? Is it possibly a bug in CXF that is causing this issue?

Until now I have not been able to find very much specifically on this issue on the web, except for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939796/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-in-cxf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), where the proposed answer is to turn of WS-Discovery... but this is not an option for us, as we actually want to use this feature.

I also tried to [disable the schema validation of CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671437/is-it-possible-to-control-set-jaxb-validation-event-handler-programmatically?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or implement an [own ValidationEventHandler for JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751249/how-to-set-custom-validationeventhandler-on-jaxb-unmarshaller-when-using-annotat), but these approaches seem not to be working for us (= nothing happens) yet either. So if anyone has more information for me on how to correctly implement one of these (but please without using an additional framework like Spring or something, so just annotation based or programmatical with the existing CXF/JAXB capabilities), I would also appreciate that.

**Additional information:**

We are using [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) as CDI framework, and our web server is [Untertow](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html). However, the deployment of the webservice endpoints is (currently still) done via javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(...), which should later on also be integrated into Undertow at some point.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Hi !  Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not... We went on to not using that part of CXF and implementing the WS-Discovery our own. Sorry that I don't have better news...